# Force.com Source Scanner Results to CSV/JSON

Tags: security-scanner

Has anyone found a nifty way to convert results from the Force.com Source Scanner into CSV or JSON?

I have over 300 small issues (mainly API version and FLS Creates), and want to push them into our Product Management Tool / Support System, but don't fancy the massive cut and paste exercise!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is this is Not possible. As to convert into CSV we need the HTML in table format but the report which Salesforce provide is not in the Tabular format. Same with the JSON.

So the only option you have left with to Copy/Paste into your tool or can create a word document and upload that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the reports are machine generated from xml files, you can certainly write code to do that, however be aware that you would be using private APIs. The code generating the reports is occasionally changed, so you will need to keep patching this.

However the general schema is pretty simple from examining the reports themselves, so you can extract this and convert it to other formats if you have access to an html parser api.